# Kibana Not Showing Any Logs (ELK Stack)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am learning ELK stack. So I have written a sample java code that churns out some log line in a file. I am trying to see if the log lines show up in Kibana UI. So I will try to explain it to best of my abilities about what I did. So first I start elasticsearch, then logstash, then kibana.

My logstash config file looks like:

```
input {
    file {
    type => "java"
    path => "C:/temp/logs/application.log"
    codec => multiline {
        pattern => "^%{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTHNUM}/%{YEAR} %{TIME}.*"
        negate => "true"
        what => "previous"
    }
  }
}

filter {

    grok {  
        match => { "message" => "%{DATE_EU:date} %{TIME:time} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:zone} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.*] \[%{DATA:thread}] %{DATA:class} - %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
        add_tag => [ "log" ]
    }
}

output {
    
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    
    # Sending properly parsed log events to elasticsearch
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

The logs that are in the log file look like this:

```
    07/06/2022 14:37:41.471 +0530 [ERROR] [main] com.cmt.ncaas.logging.LoggingTrial - Trying to log an error
07/06/2022 14:37:41.471 +0530 [DEBUG] [main] com.cmt.ncaas.logging.LoggingTrial - Trying to log an debug
07/06/2022 14:37:41.471 +0530 [TRACE] [main] com.cmt.ncaas.logging.LoggingTrial - Trying to log an trace
07/06/2022 14:37:41.471 +0530 [WARN ] [main] com.cmt.ncaas.logging.LoggingTrial - Trying to log an warn
07/06/2022 14:37:41.471 +0530 [ERROR] [main] com.cmt.ncaas.logging.LoggingTrial - Exception occured: 
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.cmt.ncaas.logging.LoggingTrial.exceptionLogging(LoggingTrial.java:39)
    at com.cmt.ncaas.logging.LoggingTrial.main(LoggingTrial.java:32)
```

After this I created an index template with pattern `logs-*`. But I dont see anything show up in Kibana.

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong. I suspect it is the input section that is messing it up. But being so new, I am not sure what I could change.

Any pointers, i much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "index" on elasticsearch output.

If you don't specify that, the logs are going to either:

"logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
OR
"ecs-logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

Those do not match your logs-* index pattern.

[See the documentation here and search the index section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index)

This should solve:

```
elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
```

Good luck